# Is current graphic only available in view's drawRect:?

Tags: iphone, graphics, uiview

I tried invoking UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() in other places other than in drawRect. It give me a NULL. Is it true that I can can only get current context in UIView's drawRect: only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, outside of drawRect, the default context is nil. Before drawRect is called, a view will push its context onto the stack, and pop it after drawRect ends.